# How does this database design look?

Tags: database-design

[image]

This is my first official design after having read a coursebook in preparation for the upcoming semester.  The goal is to have a user-based form creation/publication and submission web application.

A user should be able to create/publish a form on the site (my web server).  Then users (both the creator of the form and others) should be able to submit the form.  After that, a report could be generated and show which user submitted which answers.  I tend to over-complicate statements when simple is better.

Here is how I envision the relationships working:

- A ***USER*** belongs to many ***GROUPS***
- A ***GROUP*** consists of many ***USERS***
- Due to the many-many association, a composite entity is created.
- A ***USER*** can create many ***FORMS***
- Each ***FORM*** belongs to one ***USER***
- A ***FORM*** provides many ***QUESTIONS***
- Each ***QUESTION*** belongs to one ***FORM***
- A ***QUESTION*** has many ***ANSWERS***
- Each ***ANSWER*** goes with one ***QUESTION***
- A ***FORM*** has many ***SUBMISSIONS***
- Each ***SUBMISSION*** is tied to one ***FORM***
- A ***SUBMISSION*** has many ***SUBMISSION_ANSWERS***
- Each ***SUBMISSION_ANSWER*** is part of one ***SUBMISSION***

Answer (score 3):

Your design doesn't record *"which user submitted which answers"*.

Should there not be a relationship between `SUBMISSION` and `USER`?  You have the attribute `submission_user` but you haven't indicated that it is a foreign key to `USER`.

Should there not be a link between `SUBMISSION_ANSWER` and `ANSWER`?  How else do you know which question is being answered and what the value of the answer is?

`SUBMISSION_ANSWER.attribute_name` seems like you left something incomplete.